# Why sprintf changes the value of the number printed?

Tags: php

Why the following code

```
<?php
$x =965745973615421686;
print $x;
print '<br />';
print sprintf ( '%.0f', $x);

?>
```

prints the wrong results?

```
965745973615421686
965745973615421696
```

This is PHP7.1 on windows 10 x64.
Production will be Ubuntu 16.04 32bit.

Comment: what did you expected and why?

Comment: I expected both printed values to be the same.

Comment: It's probably because you're converting to float but can't hold enough precision in floats to accurately represent that number. Do `%d` instead

Comment: @apokryfos please make an answer with that comment

Comment: You are converting the number to float when you printf it with the format you've selected.  You might want to read up on floating point numbers. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floating point arithmetic is weird. A float is a bunch of significant digits followed by an exponent. The problem is the exponent takes space so you can only have (in a 64-bit system) is only 53 bits which is a max significant value of 9.0071993e+15. You seem to have 2 digits more than that in this case meaning the number you have, when converted to float will not have 100% precision.

You need to keep it as int by doing

```
print sprintf("%d",$x);
```

Comment: This had solved it on dev (64bit) but on the production it gives -1533253376 because it is 32bit

Comment: @AmrElAdawy Not much you can do there but upgrade production or use [GMP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php).

Answer (score 1):

You most likely run 32-bit PHP so 965745973615421686 is greater than PHP_INT_MAX:

```
var_dump(PHP_INT_MAX, 965745973615421686);
```

Under 64-bit it prints this:

```
int(9223372036854775807)
int(965745973615421686)
```

I don't currently have a 32-bit PHP setup to compare but it'll print something on this line:

```
int(2147483647)
float(...)
```

Additionally, regular type cast to string makes use of the `precision` directive so the number of decimals can vary but in `sprintf()` you define the exact decimals you want:

```
ini_set('precision', 20);
var_dump((string)1.1, sprintf('%.1f', 1.1));
```

```
string(21) "1.1000000000000000888"
string(3) "1.1"
```